# Linux CentOS path does not exist

Tags: linux, directory, centos

I'm working on Linux CentOS 6.5. 
Can someone explain to me the following:

```
[root@zwoop html]# locate l4_test
/var/www/html/l4_test
[root@zwoop html]# file /var/www/html/l4_test
/var/www/html/l4_test: cannot open `/var/www/html/l4_test' (No such file or directory)
```

I want to delete this folder, but I'm not allowed to delete it with

```
rm -R /var/www/html/l4_test
```

Because apparently it does not exist, even though it exists... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the manual describes, locate reads one or more databases prepared by "updatedb".

It may not have the latest information if it's been a while since the last updatedb.

Run it manually (updatedb) and then try locate.